# Turing Machine Arrow Definition

Tags: turing-machines

Does anyone know the exact definition of '=>', '<=' and '<=>' in the context of Turing Machines? Googling failed to provide me with the answer!

To put it into context, here's a theorem / proof.

_

**Theorem** A language L is decidable <=> both L and L' are Turing-recognisable.

**Proof**: => is obvious. For <=, we have TM’s M1 and M2 that recognise L, L' respectively. Use them to build a TM M that runs M1 and M2 in parallel until one of them accepts (which must happen). If M1 accepts M accepts too; if M2 accepts, M rejects.

Comment: This probably belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem** A language L is decidable if and only if both L and L' are Turing-recognisable.

**Proof**: L is decidable implies L and L' are Turing recognisable is obvious. For both L and L' are Turing-recognisable implies L is decidable, we have TM’s M1 and M2 that recognise L, L' respectively. Use them to build a TM M that runs M1 and M2 in parallel until one of them accepts (which must happen). If M1 accepts M accepts too; if M2 accepts, M rejects.

<==> means if and only if. A => B means A implies B. In if and only if proofs we prove double implication. In other words, in order to prove that A if and only if B then we prove that a implies B and B implies A.